# Problema con getInt de jsonResponse

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Tengo un archivo Score.php para realizar update a un campo llamado score de tipo entero en una base de datos mysql:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "basededatos");

$user_id = $_POST["id_user"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$score= $_POST["score"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET score= ? WHERE id_user=? AND username=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isi", $id_user, $username, $score);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $name, $username, $password, $date, $email, $score);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement))
{
   $response["success"] = true; 
    $response["id_user"] = $user_id; 
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;
    $response["date"] = $date;
    $response["email"] = $email;
    $response["score"] = $score;

    }

echo json_encode($response);
```

La clase en android studio que llama a ese archivo php es:

```
public class ScoreRequest extends StringRequest
{

private static final String Score_Request_URL="http://192.168.1.221/Score.php";//declaramos una constante
private Map<String, String> params;

//constructor de la clase
public ScoreRequest (int userid, String username, int scoreaux, Response.Listener<String> listener)
{
    super(Request.Method.POST,Score_Request_URL,listener, null);
    params= new HashMap<>();
    params.put("id_user", userid+"");
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("score", scoreaux+"");


}//fin de constructor
```

también tengo el activity.java donde necesito que cuando presione un Button llamado btnno realice la actualización en la base de datos del campo llamado score, y al mismo tiempo me conduzca a otro activity2 con el campo score actualizado ya que le sumo 1.

el codigo del método del Button (btnno) en activity es:

```
 btnno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            int scoreaux;
            scoreaux=Integer.parseInt(score);
            scoreaux+=1;
            final String usernameaux=username;
            final int useraux=Integer.parseInt(userid);


            Response.Listener<String> responseListener= new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse=new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success= jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if(success)
                        {



                           int user=jsonResponse.getInt("id_user");
                           String nameuser=jsonResponse.getString("username");
                           int scoreb=jsonResponse.getInt("score");


                            Intent intent=new Intent (Digits.this, Digits2.class);

                           intent.putExtra("id_user", user);
                            intent.putExtra("username", nameuser);
                           intent.putExtra("score", scoreb);




                            Digits.this.startActivity(intent);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Digits.this);
                            builder.setMessage("User or Id incorrect")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create().show();
                        }
                    }

                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }//fin de método onResponse
            };//fin de Response.Listener<String>

            ScoreRequest scoreRequest= new ScoreRequest(useraux,usernameaux,scoreaux, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(Digits.this);
            queue.add(scoreRequest);

        }//fin de onclick
    });//fin de setOnClickListener

    //fin de método btnno
```

y el codigo de activity2 es:

```
public class Digits2 extends AppCompatActivity
{
String username;
int userid, score;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_digits2);

    Intent intent =getIntent();
    score=intent.getIntExtra("score",-1);
    username=intent.getStringExtra("username");
    userid=intent.getIntExtra("id_user",-1);
}
}
```

realicé debug y esto arroja el logcat:

12-19 19:02:37.088 541-634/system_process W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
12-19 19:02:37.279 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value (JSONObject.java:160)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at matgic.com.matgic.Digits$1$1.onResponse(Digits.java:123)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at matgic.com.matgic.Digits$1$1.onResponse(Digits.java:117)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-19 19:02:37.280 2327-2327/matgic.com.matgic W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

El problema es que no me conduce al activity2
De antemano, gracias por su valioso tiempo

Comment: que te muestra en pantalla? si no te lanza el activity entonces no entra al success , puedes pegar tu JSON, algún error en el logcat?

Comment: Ya has intentado debuguear? tal vez verificar el logCat para ver si se genera una excepción o mejor dicho cuando dices que no se conduce a la activity2 al menos la aplicación trata de hacer un cambio de pantalla? Lo pregunto para saber el contexto de como has estado desarrollando y poder guiarte a una respuesta. Incluso has revisado si el llamado al archivo php se ejecuta correctamente y es un problema llamando la actividad o más bien de lo que se ejecuta antes de cambiar de activity.

Comment: Será muy útil que, en vez de poner el mensaje de error por partes en comentarios, que [edites tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/125922/edit) poniendo el mensaje de error íntegro en ella. Esta parte del mensaje da la clave del problema: **`W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject...`** Debes revisar que estás recibiendo como respuesta un JSON válido, ya que donde tú intentas recuperar un entero, lo que estás recibiendo es una cadena como esta `<br ...`. Puedes recuperar el JSON que responde la petición y revisarlo.

Comment: A todos, gracias por su invaluable ayuda, por si a alguien le es útil asi lo solucioné, resultó que en el archivo Score.php en la linea mysqli_prepare el orden de las variables es score, id_user, username y en la linea mysqli_stmt_bind_param tenia "isi", cuando debe ser "iis" por el orden de las variables de derecha a izquierda en la sentencia mysqli_prepare. Así también la linea mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $name, $username, $password, $date, $email, $score); la suprimí ya que es UPDATE la sentencia y no insert o delete.